# vpnc on Ubuntu 18.04: on wifi appears to connect, but no ping. Fine on ethernet.

Tags: vpn, 18.04, vpnc

I have a fairly fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, and I'm trying to use vpnc to connect to a remote network.

On a wired connection, everything works fine.

On wifi, it appears to connect (doesn't display any errors when connecting).  However my connection to the outside world stops working (no ping to 8.8.8.8, for instance).

Here's the command I'm running:

```
sudo vpnc /etc/vpnc/myConfigFile.conf
```

Here's the contents of the config file:

```
DPD idle timeout (our side) 0
IPSec gateway my.vpn.gateway.gov
IPSec ID ipsec
IKE Authmode psk
IPSec secret ipsec
Local Port 10008
NAT Traversal Mode natt
No Detach
Xauth username <myUsername> 
Xauth password <myPassword>
```

And here's what's in /var/log/sysLog:

```
May  3 12:53:04 panther systemd-udevd[8206]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.                                     #this is when I started the VPN
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.1192] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/11)
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.1480] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.1481] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.2872] device (tun0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.3018] keyfile: add connection in-memory (d147f959-6e50-4940-8236-9a4100107d93,"tun0")
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.3086] device (tun0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.3135] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (d147f959-6e50-4940-8236-9a4100107d93)
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.3404] device (tun0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.3448] device (tun0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.3462] device (tun0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.3467] device (tun0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.3482] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.3491] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May  3 12:53:04 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525369984.3581] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
May  3 12:53:04 panther dbus-daemon[835]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=900 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
May  3 12:53:04 panther systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
May  3 12:53:04 panther dbus-daemon[835]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May  3 12:53:04 panther systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May  3 12:53:04 panther nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: new request (2 scripts)
May  3 12:53:04 panther nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
May  3 12:53:34 panther org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1621]: [2066:2087:0503/125334.475252:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(416)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -21
May  3 12:53:34 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525370014.5319] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
May  3 12:53:34 panther NetworkManager[900]: <info>  [1525370014.5433] device (tun0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
May  3 12:53:34 panther nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [tun0]: new request (2 scripts)
May  3 12:53:34 panther nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
May  3 12:53:34 panther gnome-shell[1012]: Removing a network device that was not added         #this is when I ctrl+c out of the VPN
May  3 12:53:34 panther gnome-shell[1621]: Removing a network device that was not added
May  3 12:53:34 panther gnome-shell[1621]: JS ERROR: TypeError: connectionSettings is null#012_updateConnection@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1924:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
```

I'm not really sure how to interpret the sysLog entries, or even if that's the right place to look for clues.  I'm not even sure whether this is a problem with my 18.04 settings, a vpnc problem, a network problem, or what.  Answers I've found to similar questions seem to focus on firewall settings, but I haven't installed a firewall.  Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: I got the same issue.
The VPN connection (Cisco AnyConnect) is unstable when using WIFI.
It is fine when using Ethernet.

Comment: I don't have any new progress on this issue since I posted it.  I'm actually using AnyConnect as a workaround since I'm finding it a bit more stable on wifi than vpnc.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here : [Connecting to Cisco VPN from Ubuntu 18.04 without a Group Password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033315/connecting-to-cisco-vpn-from-ubuntu-18-04-without-a-group-password/1038863#1038863)

It's work around network-manager-openconnect-gnome